# Grabbing what the user selected for option_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following table[image]

The two options for the option_for_select in `Rate Type` are either "Flat" or "Percentage". I have the box defaulted to "Flat".

**The** **problem**:  I can't find what the user ultimately selected. If they chose Percentage I would not know. How can I find out what value they selected? I want to know because if they select "Flat", I want currency-format to be true for the `Institutional` box.

```
= form_for @payer_contract,:html => {:id => "add-payer-contract-form"} do |f|
  %table.table-base.table-striped{:id => "case-global-table"}
    %tbody
      .clone-wrapper
        - @payer_contract.phase_dates.each.with_index do |pd, index|
          =fields_for "phase_dates",pd do |p|
            %tr.clone-target{:id => 'phase-table-row', :name => 'payer_contract[phase][:i][desc]'}
              - @phase_name = t('payer_contracts.phase')+ ' ' +(index+1).to_s
              %td
                %input.field-input{type: 'text', readonly: 'readonly', placeholder: 'Phase', value: @phase_name}
              %td
                = p.select :rate_type, options_for_select(@rate_type, @selected_rate_type), :name=> "phase_dates[rate_type]-c#{index}", required: true, :style => 'width:125px'
              %td
                = p.text_field :institutional, :name=> "phase_dates[institutional]-c#{index}", class: 'field-input', 'currency-format' => (@rate_type == 'Flat')
              %td
                = p.text_field :professional, :name=> "phase_dates[professional]-c#{index}", class: 'field-input'
              %td
                %button.icon-fallback-text.clone-add{"aria-label" => "Add", :type => "button"}
                  %span.icon-add-square{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
                %button.icon-fallback-text.clone-remove{"aria-label" => "Remove", :disabled => @payer_contract.phase_dates.size > 1 ? false : true, :type => "button"}
                  %span.icon-remove-square{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
```

In the above code, `Institutional` is always showing currency format even if I choose "Percentage"  because @rate_type for some reason never finds what the user actually selected.

When I inspect the "Flat" box 2 under Rate Type, I find this:

```
<select id="phase_dates_rate_type-c1" name="phase_dates[rate_type]-c1" u-index="1" aria-invalid="false" class="valid"><option value="
```

Any ideas?

Controller looks like this:

def new

```
@payer_contract = PayerContract.new(
     id: '',
     description: '',
     type_code: {
         id: '',
         code_key: '',
         display: '',
         code_group: ''
},
     base_contract_rate: '',
     phase_dates: [{
                       id: '',
                       rate_type: '',
                       institutional: '',
                       professional: ''
                   }],
     donor_claim_phase: '',
)
@selected_rate_type = 'Flat'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `p.text_field :institutional`, isn't `pd[:rate_type]` the value you want to compare against? It looks like `@rate_type` is an array of both options.

For already saved records you can try:

```
= p.text_field :institutional, :name=> "phase_dates[institutional]-c#{index}", class: 'field-input', 'currency-format' => (pd[:rate_type] == 'Flat')
```

For the form elements you're dynamically adding with javascript you'll have to toggle the rate type in javascript.

Comment: It is still evaluating to true, for both Flat and Percentage with this. The problem is, @Selected_rate_type = 'Flat' in the controller. Should I change it to something else in the controller?

Comment: You should remove that @selected_rate_type entirely and use p.rate_type within the loop. You need a different value for each record, so you need to use the value saved on that record.

Comment: I removed @selected_rate_type, but I am not sure how to go about saving the value on each record. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you already are. Did you make a rate_type on your PhaseDate record?

Comment: yeah, it' looks like this: phase_dates: [{
                           id: '',
                           rate_type: '',
                           institutional: '',
                           professional: ''
                       }],

Comment: hmmm, I just tried it out. It says: "undefined method `rate_type'". I'll update main post with what the controller looks like. Any idea why I can't use p.rate_type?

Comment: Just tried the (p[:rate_type] and it is saying " undefined method `[]' " ...hmmm